# How to incorporate a user's paypal idea into a php based web forum?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have learned how to make a palpal subscription option for my users.  It is pretty easy.  I just log into my paypal account page and create a button and customize it to be for a repeating subscription.

The question I want to ask here is this.  Without giving it a try myself as a test, I don't know what the process will look like.  What does the process look like?  What I am most interested in is whether or not some sort of username or identifier is obtained for record keeping.

Also, I assume that the user will be taken to a different page when they click on the subscribe button.

Answer (score 0):

Paypal provides a lot of options for integration with websites. The easy one is

***PayPal HTML buttons*** — Simply log in to the PayPal website to create, and optionally customize, a payment button. Then copy and paste the payment button's HTML code snippet to your website. Use this option if your HTML or web programming skills are limited and you sell only a few products on your site.

For more information refer:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/pps_integration/